# Wrong flags arrangement after dynamically set the data on function afterSetExtremes

Tags: highcharts, flags

I have a highstock graph with flags that initially is correctly set.

See on Figure 1:
[image]

The graph's data is loaded dynamically when the vertical scroll bar is changed. The only thing that changes is the series data with the function

```
function afterSetExtremes(e) {
    var new_data_to_be_loaded = getNewDataToBeLoaded();
    chart.series[0].setData(new_data_to_be_loaded);
}
```

The new series data is loaded correctly but the flags is incorreclty re-arranged, se the Figure 2:

[image]

**So what's wrong on the setting, since the chart.series[0].setData just set the series not the previous flags added?**

**Almost a solution:**

I found that setdata(data, false), setting the animation/redraw to false solve the problem of wrong flag positioning.

Take a look at that: http://jsfiddle.net/b6b63nwy/10/

**But this did raise another problem:** the series tooltip does not appear anymore. **Is this a highstocks bug?**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qfuevmqL/ On the example, the flags are positioned correctly. Can you recreate the issue on jsfiddle? How do you load new data?

Comment: I did it on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b6b63nwy/ it worked.
I think there's something related to redraw or animation because it work sometimes. Sometimes the animation of the new series is update but the flags aren't updated on the Y axis, but the X axis flags' position is updated. When this error happens, if I do a little resize on browser's window the flags goes to the right place.

Comment: @morganfree, take a look at that: http://jsfiddle.net/b6b63nwy/7/ the highstocks just bugs, it appears to be in an infinite loop when afterSetExtremes event is triggered. If I reduce the number of elements the graph doesn't bugs: http://jsfiddle.net/b6b63nwy/6/

Comment: It takes some time at the beggining, but the flags render eventually, but I think you have some options which might helpful with the performance. Turning off scrollbar.liveRedraw http://jsfiddle.net/b6b63nwy/8/, disabling animation/redraw in setData, depending on your needs http://jsfiddle.net/b6b63nwy/9/

Comment: Take a look at that: http://jsfiddle.net/b6b63nwy/11/
scrollbar.liveRedraw = false and setdata(data, false), setting the animation/redraw to false did raise another bug: the series tooltip does not appear anymore. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer:

http://forum.highcharts.com/highstock-usage/bug-series-tooltip-doesn-t-render-when-use-series-setdata-t37593/

=====================================================================

If you take a look at the Series.setData section in the official API, you will find that the second argument is a Boolean property which tells if redraw the chart. Instead of setData, try to use Series.update() function.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Series.update